# Android check if device supports inapp billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I follow this guide

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

When I do the bind service right at the beginning, how can I check if Google Play really supports in app billing?

Comment: think I found it, is this correct? int response = service.isBillingSupported(3, packageName, "inapp");

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase) on * In-App Billing Purchasing Items*

> Your application sends a isBillingSupported request to Google Play to determine that the target version of the In-app Billing API that you are using is supported.